# Update List-View when model change

Tags: listview, javafx-2

I'm not able to update my `javafx.scene.control.ListView<Todo>` control.
As you can see the listview displays the headline property.
When i change the headline of a todo the list-view still displays the old value.

```
public class Todo {

private StringProperty  headline    = new SimpleStringProperty();

private StringProperty  description = new SimpleStringProperty();

public Todo(String aHeadline) {
    this.setHeadline(aHeadline);
}

public Todo(String aHeadline, String aDescription) {
    this(aHeadline);
    this.description.set(aDescription);

}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description.get();
}

public StringProperty descriptionProperty() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String aDescription) {
    this.description.set(aDescription);
}

public String getHeadline() {
    return this.headline.get();
}

public void setHeadline(String aHeadline) {
    this.headline.set(aHeadline);
}

public static ObservableList<Todo> getMockups() {
    try {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(TodoXmlParser.getTodosFromXml(Paths.get("/Todos.xml")));
    } catch (JDOMException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.headline.get();
}
```

}

```
 this.listView = new ListView<>();
 this.listView.setItems(Todo.getMockups());
 this.listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setHeadline("new");
```

I'm missing a method like `listview.refresh(), or update()`
So what's the right way to do this?

**Edit**: I find a way of doing this, but i would be glad, if someone can explain the "official" way of doing this.

```
    void updateListView(Todo todo) {
    int index = this.listView.getItems().indexOf(todo);
    this.listView.getItems().remove(todo);
    this.listView.getItems().add(index, todo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. It is not really beautifull but it does the job. I'll still dig for a better way to do it...

```
    int index = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    System.out.println(listView.getItems());

    ObservableList<Todo> olist = listView.getItems();
    olist.get(index).setHeadline("new");
    listView.setItems(null);
    listView.setItems(olist);
```

OR

```
    listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setHeadline("new 2");
    ObservableList<Todo> olist = listView.getItems();
    listView.setItems(null);
    listView.setItems(olist);
```

Here's the **"better" way**

Make a little change in your Todo class so that you have a `getHeadline()`method that returns a StringProperty instead of a string.

Then, make your own implementation of the CellFactory and bind to textProperty the StringProperty given by the getHeadline() method :

```
    listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Todo>, ListCell<Todo>>() {
        public ListCell<Todo> call(ListView<Todo> param) {
            final ListCell<Todo> cell = new ListCell<Todo>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Todo item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null) {
                        textProperty().bind(item.getHeadline());
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Now when you make a change to the underlying list the corresponding cell is updated

Comment: Thanks for this workaround, but i hope there's a better way of doing this. I'll wait some days before i'll accept your answer. Also i edited my post for a more performance gently way of updating specific items.

Comment: Found a better way, updating my post.

Comment: And by the way your way of updating the list is more efficient if you only select one item... If you have a big list and if you select a large number of items, the `listView.getItems().remove(selectedList)` will take more time than removing and adding the list again because it will have to fetch every occurence in the list. I fell into this pit recently ... I hope everything is working fine for you now.